# blackberry sdk 4.5 limiting resource bundle to 99 keys?

Tags: java, blackberry, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have been using an unique resource bundle for all my project. When I reached the key 98 no new key gets found on res.getString(int). It throws MissingResourceException. I can add it but then can't be found.

If I just change to SDK 4.6.0 then It works great.

Anyone aware of this limitation? Am I doing something wrong?

Must say I rebuild the project and deleted by hand interface code generated for the resource without any result.

Compile for 4.5 is very important because I must support Blackberry models like 8100.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a project with 740 resource keys, and it builds and executes just fine on BBOS 4.5.
Are you using the latest release of the 4.5 tools?   I am on 4.5.0.28.